# xpath start with non-ascii character (php domdocument)

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom -> loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sst><si><t>andy</t>    </si><si><t>billy</t></si><si><t>中文</t></si></sst>');

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$entities = $xpath -> query("//t[starts-with(.,'a')]/text()");
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    echo $entity -> nodeValue;
}
?>
```

In the above example, I would like to query all t elements in which the value starts with a specific letter. I could pick the words started with A-Z but I don't know how to handle those case that's started with a non-ascii character.

```
    $entities = $xpath -> query("//t[not (starts-with(.,'a') or starts-with(.,'b'))]/text()");
```

Apart from the above approach (that may need 26 starts-with(.,'a').....xyz), is there a smarter method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first character inside the current element

`substring(.,1,1)`

Replace a list of characters with `a`

`translate(substring(.,1,1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')`

Validate that the result is not `a`

`translate(substring(.,1,1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa') != 'a'`

Complete example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom ->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><sst><si><t>andy</t>    </si><si><t>billy</t></si><si><t>中文</t></si></sst>');

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$entities = $xpath->evaluate(
  "//t[translate(substring(.,1,1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa') != 'a']/text()"
);
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
  echo $entity->nodeValue;
}
```

Output:

```
中文
```